# Android - picking file with specific extension (pdf & docx)

Tags: java, android

I used this code for video

```
public void pickVideo()
{
    Intent pickVideoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(pickVideoIntent, PICK_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch (requestCode){
                case PICK_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
                    Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                    videoPicked(videoUriToRealPath(selectedVideo));
                    break;
        .
        .
        .
        public String videoUriToRealPath(Uri videoUri){
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(videoUri, proj, null, null, null);
            String videoPath = "";

            try{
                if (cursor != null){
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        videoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                }
            }finally{
                cursor.close();
            }

            return videoPath;
        }
```

and it's working. I want to set **PICK_FILE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE** as one of cases. I've defined it:

```
   public void pickFile()
    {
        Intent pickFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pickFileIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(pickFileIntent, PICK_FILE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
    }
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                switch (requestCode){
                case PICK_FILE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
                    Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
                    filePicked(fileUriToRealPath(selectedFile));
        .
        .
        .
        public String fileUriToRealPath(Uri fileUri){
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Files.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, proj, null, null, null);
            String filePath = "";

            try{
                if (cursor != null){
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.Media.DATA);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                }
            }finally{
                cursor.close();
            }

            return filePath;
        }
```

Actually it's not working.  extension .PDF and .DOCX in my files. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to search on the whole sdcard.

**searchDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());**

```
public void searchDir(File dir){
    String docExt = ".doc";
    String pdfExt = ".pdf";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++){
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()){
                searchDir(listFile[i]);
            }else{
                if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(docExt)){
                    //Do what ever u want
                }else if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pdfExt)){
                    //Do what ever u want
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've updated my question.